# Can i use nltk to build an answer engine using wikipedia's content

Tags: python, search, nlp, nltk

I have built an answer engine using wikipedia's content with php. It just returns the most relevant wikipedia article for a particular query which in most of the cases turn out to be useles.The users tend to ask in a question format like "`what is the height of wayne rooney" and i want to give the exact height of rooney which is available in his wikipedia article. Can i solve this if i use nltk. Please advice.

Comment: Ask a real question... and BTW, check [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+monsters+in+loch+ness)

Comment: More or less, yes.  Now go do it and come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: I think this is a pretty good question, check this https://github.com/pavlobaron/wpcorpus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in general: yes it is possible, BUT it is a very difficult task to build such a program.

what you are searching trying to build is called a 'semantic search engine' (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_search)) and there is a lot of research going on, how we can build a 'semantic web' and how to extract information of webpages, so that questions like the one you mentioned can be answered by computers, instead of just supplying links to relevant documents.
but the results are still far from perfect.

one of the better semantic search engines seems to be [trueknowledge](http://www.trueknowledge.com/q/what_is_the_height_of_wayne_rooney) and of course the previously mentioned [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What+is+the+weight+of+1+liter+rice%3F) (which has its strengths in science).

if you really want to build such a semantic search engine the nltk might provide some helpful basic tools, but don't expect it to be an easy task at all.